# Problems to set ytick within colorbar using TikZ/PGFPlots, no axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to do an colorbar in TikZ without any axis beside. This is what I got so far by using the help provided by this excellent forum.

[image: Pic 1: result at the moment]

My problem: **I want to have the y-tick as follows: -2e-3, -1,5e-3, -1e-3,...,2e-3.**

See for example picture 2 from another program;

[image: Pic 2: y-tick like it should look like]

Using something like `$-2e-3$` in the y-tick doesn't work;

> Error:! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '$-2^{-3}$' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '$-2^{-3}$'.

Here is my code untill now. (Using this code I get picture 1 shown above.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={12pt,12pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    scale only axis,                % 
    height=0pt,                     % Grafik auf größe null
    width=0pt,                      % Grafik auf größe null
    colorbar sampled,               % Diskrete Stufung
    colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0.68235,0,1);
            rgb(9pt)=(0,0.1216, 1);
            rgb(17pt)=(0, 0.69412, 1); 
            rgb(26pt)=(0, 1, 0.6863); 
            rgb(34pt)=(0, 1, 0.098); 
            rgb(43pt)=(0.557,1,0); 
            rgb(51pt)=(1, 0.8353, 0); 
            rgb(60pt)=(1, 0.2275, 0);  
            rgb(63pt)=(1,0.02745,0)},
    colorbar style={
        title={$J$ in $\frac{A}{m^2}$},     % Titel über Colorbar
        ylabel= {$\cdot e^{-3}$},           % Beschriftung seitlich, text                                                             gedreht
        samples=9,                  % Anzahl diskreter Schritte, so viele wie yticks
        width=15,                   % Breite der Colorbar (des farbigen Bereichs)
        height=220,                 % Höhe der Colorbar
        ytick={-2, -1.5, -1,..., 2},% yticks Angabe einzeln mit komma getrennt,                                               oder schrittweise mit 1,2,...,5
        point meta min=-2, %neu     % Beginn Colorbar, beachte yticks min
        point meta max=2, %neu      % Ende Colorbar, beachte yticks max
        yticklabel style={
            text width=2.5em,       % Abstand yticks zu colorbar
            align=right,            % 
        }
    }
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I hope you understand my problem and what I want to do.

I would be very happy if someone could help me changing the y-tick values into something like `2e^{-3}`.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer and answer my question. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

One way to achieve this is to do the following:

1. Use the actual values for the `meta` range, so `point meta min=-2e-3, point meta max=2e3`
2. Switch off the overall scaling of the tick labels: `scaled y ticks = false`
3. Parse and format the tick values using the `siunitx` package, which gives very fine control over the number formatting. Load `\usepackage{siunitx}`, then set

   ```
   yticklabel={
       \num[
           scientific-notation = fixed,
           fixed-exponent = -3,
           output-exponent-marker = \text{e},
           round-integer-to-decimal = true,
           round-mode = places,
           round-precision = 1
       ]{\tick}
   }
   ```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={12pt,12pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    scale only axis,                % 
    height=0pt,                     % Grafik auf größe null
    width=0pt,                      % Grafik auf größe null
    colorbar sampled,               % Diskrete Stufung
    colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0.68235,0,1);
            rgb(9pt)=(0,0.1216, 1);
            rgb(17pt)=(0, 0.69412, 1); 
            rgb(26pt)=(0, 1, 0.6863); 
            rgb(34pt)=(0, 1, 0.098); 
            rgb(43pt)=(0.557,1,0); 
            rgb(51pt)=(1, 0.8353, 0); 
            rgb(60pt)=(1, 0.2275, 0);  
            rgb(63pt)=(1,0.02745,0)},
    colorbar style={
        title={$J$ in $\frac{A}{m^2}$},     % Titel über Colorbar gedreht
        samples=9,                  % Anzahl diskreter Schritte, so viele wie yticks
        width=15,                   % Breite der Colorbar (des farbigen Bereichs)
        height=220,                 % Höhe der Colorbar
        %ytick={-2, -1.5, -1,..., 2},% yticks Angabe einzeln mit komma getrennt,                                               oder schrittweise mit 1,2,...,5
        point meta min=-2e-3, %neu     % Beginn Colorbar, beachte yticks min
        point meta max=2e-3, %neu      % Ende Colorbar, beachte yticks max
        scaled y ticks = false,
        yticklabel={
            \num[
                scientific-notation = fixed,
                fixed-exponent = -3,
                output-exponent-marker = \text{e},
                round-integer-to-decimal = true,
                round-mode = places,
                round-precision = 1
            ]{\tick}
        },
        yticklabel style={
            text width=4em,       % Abstand yticks zu colorbar
            align=right,            % 
        }
    }
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution.

With e notation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido,pstricks}

\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.68235,0,1}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0,0.1216,1}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0,0.69412,1}
\definecolor{color4}{rgb}{0,1,0.6863}
\definecolor{color5}{rgb}{0,1,0.098}
\definecolor{color6}{rgb}{0.557,1,0}
\definecolor{color7}{rgb}{1,0.8353,0}
\definecolor{color8}{rgb}{1,0.2275,0}
\definecolor{color9}{rgb}{1,0.02745,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.33,-0.15)(2.3,8.7)
  \multido{\i = 1+1}{8}{\psframe[dimen = m, fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = color\i](!0 \i\space 1 sub)(0.5,\i)}
  \multido{\iA = 0+2, \iB = -2+1}{5}{\rput[r](1.9,\iA){$\iB\mathrm{e}^{-3}$}}
  \multido{\i = 1+2, \r = -1.5+1}{4}{\rput[r](1.9,\i){$\r\mathrm{e}^{-3}$}}
  \rput(0.25,8.5){$J$ in $\frac{A}{\textup{m}^{2}}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

With scientific notation, which is better in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido,pstricks}

\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.68235,0,1}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0,0.1216,1}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0,0.69412,1}
\definecolor{color4}{rgb}{0,1,0.6863}
\definecolor{color5}{rgb}{0,1,0.098}
\definecolor{color6}{rgb}{0.557,1,0}
\definecolor{color7}{rgb}{1,0.8353,0}
\definecolor{color8}{rgb}{1,0.2275,0}
\definecolor{color9}{rgb}{1,0.02745,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.33,-0.15)(2.3,8.7)
  \multido{\i = 1+1}{8}{\psframe[dimen = m, fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = color\i](!0 \i\space 1 sub)(0.5,\i)}
  \multido{\iA = 0+2, \iB = -2+1}{5}{\rput[r](2.3,\iA){$\iB \cdot 10^{-3}$}}
  \multido{\i = 1+2, \r = -1.5+1}{4}{\rput[r](2.3,\i){$\r \cdot 10^{-3}$}}
  \rput(0.25,8.5){$J$ in $\frac{A}{\textup{m}^{2}}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Comment: Cool as always, but the OP was specifically asking for a scientific notation, like `$2e-3$`.

Comment: @PierPaolo That notation looks really bad, I think, but I'll add another solution.