# Setting ytick at defined positions within colorbar using TikZ/PGFPlots, no axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Yesterday I posted my first question ([Problems to set ytick within colorbar using TikZ/PGFPlots, no axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228854/problems-to-set-ytick-within-colorbar-using-tikz-pgfplots-no-axis)) and I got really fantastic answers. Now it works as I wanted it to be. But I have still a small problem and apparently I am too stupid to solve this issue. Caused to some problems with the registration (now it works!) and my forum status I am not able to comment my last post.

Now, my problem:
I want to do a colorbar in TikZ without any axis beside. This is what I got so far by using the help provided by this super forum.

[image: actual status of colorbar]

But I want to set the yticks at defined positions, like shown in picture 2 at the minimum value of the bar 7.50e6, then 8.75e6, 1e7, ..., up to the maximum value of the bar (1.75e7). Picture 2 shows my desired solution concerning the yticks.

[image]

How can I self define the yticks?

Here is my code until now:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    scale only axis,                % 
    height=0pt,                     % Grafik auf größe null
    width=0pt,                      % Grafik auf größe null
    colorbar sampled,               % Diskrete Stufung
    colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0.68235,0,1);
            rgb(9pt)=(0,0.1216, 1);
            rgb(17pt)=(0, 0.69412, 1); 
            rgb(26pt)=(0, 1, 0.6863); 
            rgb(34pt)=(0, 1, 0.098); 
            rgb(43pt)=(0.557,1,0); 
            rgb(51pt)=(1, 0.8353, 0); 
            rgb(60pt)=(1, 0.2275, 0);  
            rgb(63pt)=(1,0.02745,0)},
    colorbar style={
        title={$J$ in $\frac{A}{\si{\square\m}}$},     % Titel über Colorbar gedreht si unit m^2
        %title={$J$ in $\frac{A}{m^{2}}$},              % Titel über Colorbar gedreht
        samples=75,                  % Anzahl diskreter Schritte, so viele wie yticks
        width=15,                   % Breite der Colorbar (des farbigen Bereichs)
        height=220,                 % Höhe der Colorbar
        point meta min=7500000, %neu     % Beginn Colorbar, beachte yticks min
        point meta max=17500000, %neu      % Ende Colorbar, beachte yticks max
        scaled y ticks = false,
        yticklabel={
            \num[
                %scientific-notation = fixed,
                scientific-notation = true,
                %fixed-exponent = 5,
                exponent-product=\cdot,
                %output-exponent-marker = \text{e},
                round-integer-to-decimal = true,
                round-mode = figures,
                round-precision = 3,
            ]{\tick}
        },
        yticklabel style={
            text width=4em,       % Abstand yticks zu colorbar
            align=right,            %          
        }
    }
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't think those are very helpful tick positions, but here's how you can get them.

The simplest way is the "brute force method":
Set `ytick = {7.5e6, 8.75e6, 1e7, 1.125e7, 1.25e7, 1.375e7, 1.5e7, 1.625e7, 1.75e7}` to manually specify all the tick positions.

But because that's not very flexible, you might want to use the `foreach` syntax of `ytick = {7.5e6, 8.75e6, ..., 1.75e7}`. However, that will fail with a `dimension too large` error because this mechanism uses basic TeX arithmetic, which can't handle such large numbers. So we'll have to use some intermediate steps:

- Contrary to what I told you before, specify the axis limits in scaled units:

  ```
  point meta min=7.5,
  point meta max=17.5
  ```
- This allows you to specify the tick positions using the `foreach` syntax:

  ```
  ytick = {7.5, 8.75, ..., 17.5}
  ```
- Within the tick labels, you can then scale the tick values back:

  ```
  yticklabel={
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed} % Necessary for handling large values
  \pgfmathparse{\tick*1e6} % Scale the tick values
      \num[
          scientific-notation = true,
          exponent-product=\cdot,
          round-integer-to-decimal = true,
          round-mode = places,
          round-precision = 3,
      ]{\pgfmathresult}
  ```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    scale only axis,                % 
    height=0pt,                     % Grafik auf größe null
    width=0pt,                      % Grafik auf größe null
    colorbar sampled,               % Diskrete Stufung
    colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0.68235,0,1);
            rgb(9pt)=(0,0.1216, 1);
            rgb(17pt)=(0, 0.69412, 1); 
            rgb(26pt)=(0, 1, 0.6863); 
            rgb(34pt)=(0, 1, 0.098); 
            rgb(43pt)=(0.557,1,0); 
            rgb(51pt)=(1, 0.8353, 0); 
            rgb(60pt)=(1, 0.2275, 0);  
            rgb(63pt)=(1,0.02745,0)},
    colorbar style={
        title={$J$ in $\frac{A}{\si{\square\m}}$},     % Titel über Colorbar gedreht si unit m^2
        %title={$J$ in $\frac{A}{m^{2}}$},              % Titel über Colorbar gedreht
        samples=75,                  % Anzahl diskreter Schritte, so viele wie yticks
        width=15,                   % Breite der Colorbar (des farbigen Bereichs)
        height=220,                 % Höhe der Colorbar
        point meta min=7.5, %neu     % Beginn Colorbar, beachte yticks min
        point meta max=17.5, %neu      % Ende Colorbar, beachte yticks max
        scaled y ticks = false,
       ytick = {7.5, 8.75, ..., 17.5},
        yticklabel={
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathparse{\tick*1e6}
            \num[
                %scientific-notation = fixed,
                scientific-notation = true,
                %fixed-exponent = 5,
                exponent-product=\cdot,
                %output-exponent-marker = \text{e},
                round-integer-to-decimal = true,
                round-mode = places,
                round-precision = 3,
            ]{\pgfmathresult}
        },
        yticklabel style={
            text width=4em,       % Abstand yticks zu colorbar
            align=right,            %          
        }
    }
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

In case you need to handle huge numbers (larger than 1E10), `siunitx` will choke when you try to display the numbers using scientific format. In that case, you can fall back to the PGF number parser, which, while not quite as powerful as `siunitx`, also allows for a decent amount of customization:

```
\pgfmathparse{\tick*1e6}
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
```

Comment: Hi Jake! Thank you very much for your fast response. I know that the ytick positions are not the best ones, but i have to do them like that...The "brute force method" works fine. Unfortunately the other method using the foreach syntax doesn't work. If i copy your posted code i'll get nevertheless dimension errors: !Number too big.\I_siunitx_tmpa_tl -> 5000000000\end{axis} and so on

Comment: @DC3: From the error message, it sounds like you're using limits different from the 7.5e6 and 17.5e6, correct? It seems like `siunitx` can't process the entire number range that `/pgf/fpu` can handle. I wasn't aware of that. I've edited my answer showing an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, i set the limits exactly like you in your code (7.5 and 17.5). I don't know why i get the '!Number too big.' error. I just copied your code one to one. Concerning your alternative: this works but it needs two lines for ticks containing 3 numbers (e.g.:8.75*10^6). This doesn't look to pretty ;) Thank you!

Comment: @DC3: Hm, strange that you get that error message. Maybe we're using different versions of PGF and/or PGFPlots. About the alternative solution needing two lines: Change `text width=4em` to `text width=6em` (or something like that).