# PGF colorbar cuts off max value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to generate a whole load of colorbars with custom min and max values.

From reading this SE I have managed to get this working:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    scale only axis,
    height=0pt,
    width=0pt,
    colormap/jet,
   colorbar,
   point meta min=0.0,
   point meta max=0.2860,
    colorbar style={ height= 10 cm},xtick={0,0.2860}]
    \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image: broken colorbar]

It cuts off the top of the colorbar including the max value.

1) Why is this and how can I fix it?

2) How can I make the scale so it just has the min and max values?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't do this. Just add ``[border= 5mm]`` (or size on your wish) to the ``\documentclass``. Than you will see, that your picture is complete.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the white space. Is there no way of making it so the scale just shows min and max? This guy does it:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120174/creating-a-colormap-in-tikz-pgfplots-no-axis Add this as an answer and I will mark it correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems: 
- `standalone` packages, which without defined border, for example `border=5mm` is (to) close to border of picture;
- y range of your picture. If you set `point meta max=0.3, than the maximal value of your plot will appear.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    scale only axis,
    height=0pt,
    width=0pt,    
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar,
    point meta min=0.0,
    point meta max=0.2860,
    colorbar style={height=4cm,
            /pgf/number format/precision=3,
            ytick={0,0.286}}]
    \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

For how to put only min and max value o your diagram, I don't know.

**Edit:**
Considering comment of @Grimler, you can obtain:

[image]

Now the my MWE is complete ...

Comment: Set `colorbar style={height=5 cm,ytick={0,.286}}` to only display min and max tick

Comment: Yes, I just figured out this. But have a problem: how to prevent rounding ``0.286`` to ``0.29``? If i added this option to ``colorbar style``, that extra border of standalone is not necessary, since presence of ``ytick=0.286`` and his label `inner sep`` move standalone above border enough away.

Comment: There's probably some good way to do it, see for example [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229008/setting-ytick-at-defined-positions-within-colorbar-using-tikz-pgfplots-no-axis). You can do it the manual way by setting the `yticklabels` yourself.

Comment: As you can see in my (last edited) answer, temporary I managed my problem (with setting``number ``format/precision=3`)`. I will carefully examine topics in link you provide. Thank you.

Comment: Great that you figured it out! The link I provided plays around with the `precision=...` command as well.